# Customize Internet Explorer for showing help

Tags: java

The company I work for want to put their help files online and they want it to look like the online help in Excel. This is a browser with minimum functionality, the addressbar is removed and so are most of the buttons except for basic navigation. I am not even sure if this actually is Internet Explorer come to think of it. I cannot find a way to customize the browser that is opened through Desktop.browse though. Does anyone know if this is possible or if Excel is using another browser for Excel help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Office has its own help system, the Microsoft Office Help Viewer, `CLVIEW.EXE`.  It's not just a customized version of IE.

Have you tried the [Internet Explorer Administration Kit (IEAK)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/bb219517.aspx)?  Perhaps it will meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's all possible.  You'll need to read up on Javascript so see how to switch off the address bar, menus, etc and then use CSS to make the content look pretty.

Incidentally, the main browser window IE is an ActiveX control and can also be embedded without too much trouble.